# IdentityServer4 with ASP.Net Core App : Performance issue - too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have an ASP.Net Core WebApp and a separate IdentityServer4 STS app with UI running on IIS. IS4 uses PostgreSQL.

- User clicks login
- App tries to load the default page (Loading.cshtml), IS4 checks user is unauthorized and redirects to IS4 login page
- User login via IS4 UI and gets redirected to ASP.Net Core App

Issue is

The first set of calls, checking unauthorized access and redirect to login page takes 8-9secs
[image]

The second set of calls, after authentication, redirect to ASP.Net Core App takes 25-28secs

[image]
The app works fine in debugging mode, but I am seeing this performance issue when hosted in Azure.

Technical info:

- Certificate (pfx file) is hosted in Azure with a 2048/sha256 encryption. Someone said the encryption part might be taking time so kept it at the lowest level.
- Caching has been enabled for all stores in IS4

Not sure what I am missing, but this level of slow performance is unacceptable. Can you please help?

**Update 1**: Including Azure AppInsights data
[image]

**Update 2 - Resolved**: Found out what is causing the performance issue.

I thought it was the Ids4 API calls that are causing the issue and hence upgraded the Azure AppService Plan and still did not see any difference. Later noticed there are close to 35+ scripts getting executed.

So updated the Azure PostgreSQL plan from Basic to next tier - General Purpose and the performance increased drastically. The issue was with the Azure PostgreSQL through put.

Here is the difference:
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using Azure AppInsights to get a handle on where the time is being spent. The normal token signing operations are too intensive so I wouldn't worry about - the thing that's really expensive (by design) is password hashing.

Comment: I guest you are using Ids4 and azure sql server. Try to deploy the app on an on-premise server, or you have to pay more to azure to make it works smoothly like it is on your local dev pc. Azure is not bad but it require you have to tun your code carefully. I am not sure IdentityServer4 it is.

Comment: @DanNguyen Ids4 is running on Azure App Service plan 
**P2V2, 420 total ACU, 7 GB memory, Dv2-Series compute equivalent**, which I assume is more than enough for Ids4 STS. It uses PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks @DanNguyen. I deployed Ids4 locally with local db and everything worked flawlessly. I targeted Azure PostgreSQL and started to see issues. I found the root cause and updated in the description.

Comment: Please lock the question by marking your post as answer, or repost the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the latest update - the issue was with the Azure infrastructure. DB was configured on a shared resrouce. Updating the hardware to premium resolved the issue.